# Socket.io Check connection

Tags: javascript, laravel, socket.io

I want to check if the client is connected to socket server.
I don't mean the disconnect event.
Just wanted to check if it is connected to socket server on the client side.

When it is disconnected, I can find bellow image.
[image]

I think this means it check connection with specific time interval.
I can't find this function.
How can I check connection?

Comment: I think this means that the client can not connect at all. You should expand this connection and look into why you get this error. You can try checking different error messages with Chrome and FF Dev Edition.

Answer (score 0):

For checking the connection you want to do something like this from the client:

```
io.on('connect', (e) => { console.log('connected!'); }
```

That is the event that happens when the client connects to the server. Based on your screenshot I think you may have a larger issue as that error means the connection can't even be created.

Based on the comment you might want something like this:

```
const socket = io(server_ip+':3000/'); 
var isSocketConnected = false; 
socket.on('connect', () => { isSocketConnected = true; socketEvent(); }); 
socket.on('reconnect', () => { isSocketConnected  = true; socketEvent(); }); 
socket.on('disconnect', () => { isSocketConnected  = false; socketEvent(); }); 

const socketEvent = (event) => { 
    console.log(isSocketConnected);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew
`const socket = io(server_ip+':3000/');
var isSocketConnected = false;
socket.on('connect', () => {
isSocketConnected = true;});
socket.on('reconnect', () => {
isSocketConnected  = true;
});
socket.on('disconnect', () => {
isSocketConnected  = false;
});
console.log(isSocketConnected);` Above is what I've used.
 But I'm always get "false" log even when socket connected.
 I think this is due to async issue. How can I solve this?

Comment: Yeah so you're not going to get a change on `isSocketConnected` because there's nothing changing that state. What you might want to do is have a function that gets called when `connect` is called and that will show the proper state of the socket connection.

Comment: I updated the answer to include what that could look like